# Getting resource ID or InputStream from ImageView Drawable

Tags: android, view, imageview

I am developing a `GifView` class, extending `android.view.ImageView` to show an animation gif in Android.

The problem is getting `android:src="@drawable/myGif"` from XML layout to load it in Movie automatically. When I override `setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)` to intercept default android behaviour, I have two differents ways to do it: getting the id resource from `@drawable/myGif` and save it for later use, or load it on demand in Movie. But with the latter option I need to convert Drawable in InputStream unused compress method from Bitmap class to can safe GIF layers.

How can I do it?

```
public class GifView extends ImageView {

    ...
private Movie movie;
private int resId;

public GifView(Context context) {

    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {

    // ONE OF THOSE WAYS TO DO

    // this.redId = ...

    // this.movie = Movie.decodeStream(...);
}

    ...
}
```

Comment: you cant do it, what you can do however is a custom Drawable that uses gif under thw hood

Comment: I don´t have any problem to work with this class, because I have a method to load gif in Movie (Necesary to do in code but is not problem). But I would want an example of your suggestion please.

Comment: just extend Drawable class and override draw. method with drawing your Movie there

Comment: But this way not found for me because MyDrawable class will not be used by Android when layout will be inflated... I want automatized the job the maximun possible.

Comment: you cannot setup your custom Drawable via xml, you must set it by calling ImageView.setImageDrawable()

Comment: Of course, Now I do so, well, I setup calling my own class method, but my idea was to do automatically.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can do it automatically, but does it really pay of?

```
public class GifImageView extends ImageView {
    private final static String TAG = "GifImageView";

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        int[] attrArray = {
                android.R.attr.src
        };
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrArray);
        int id = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        a.recycle();

        if (id != 0) {
            try {
                Drawable d = new GifDrawable(getResources(), id);
                setImageDrawable(d);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "GifImageView " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    class GifDrawable extends Drawable implements Runnable {
        ...
    }
}
```